# how to make external svg color's change on hover if it's in a pseudo class in css

Tags: html, css, svg, hover, pseudo-element

I just want the html file in that area , I dont want to use      or any of those i just have the Curiosity  and persistence on doing it using css pseudo .
I have seen a website did it already as i think in his navigation bar 
visit https://www.nationalww2museum.org?

i tried many methods but it seems impossible by my knowledge.

** THAT'S HTML **

```
<li id="upper-header-content-nav-ul-li" style="margin-left: 30px;">
<a href="#select" id="upper-header-content-nav-ul-li-a">SELECT LANGUAGE</a>
</li>
```

** THAT'S CSS **

```
#upper-header-content-nav-ul-li-a[href="#select"]::before{
    background-image: url(world1.svg) ;
    content: '';
    height: 22px;
    width: 27px;
    margin-top: 1px;
    display: inline-block;
    size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: I believe you'll have to have a separate SVG, ie. `::before { background-image: url( world1-hover.svg ); }`. If the SVG were an inline element, you could use `fill: currentColor` to change it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have seen a website did it already as i think in his navigation bar visit https://www.nationalww2museum.org

The navigation bar of this site uses icon fonts, not SVG images. It is not possible to change the color of an external SVG integrated by URL.

[image]

Comment: I will try that ,
Thank you .